# trying to build android app using ionic

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework, sdk

I installed sdk on my ubuntu using these commands [here](https://gist.github.com/wenzhixin/43cf3ce909c24948c6e7)

and here is my sdk manager photo
[image]

when I try to build app using `ionic build android` I get the error below

> Error: Please install Android target: "android-23".
>
> Hint: Open the SDK manager by running:
>   /home/hunter/Documents/android-sdk-linux/tools/android You will
>   require:
>   1. "SDK Platform" for android-23
>   2. "Android SDK Platform-tools (latest)
>   3. "Android SDK Build-tools" (latest)

help me please!

Answer (score 1):

[image]

Uncheck "Installed" checkbox, and install the package named SDK Platform, under the needed API folder, SDK Platform-tools and Android SDK Build-tools

Comment: there isn't anything under Extras!